# error in compiling c program in ubuntu "storage size of time_struct isn't know"

Tags: c, ubuntu, compiler-errors

**hi,i try to compile a C program usig gcc but get this error:**

timerc.c: In function ‘timer_’:
timerc.c:32:16: error: storage size of ‘Time_Struct’ isn’t known

here is the program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#if TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME
# include <sys/time.h>
# include <time.h>
#else
# if HAVE_SYS_TIME_H
#  include <sys/time.h>
# else
#  include <time.h>
# endif
#endif
void timer_(long *UnixSysTime)
{
  int dummy;
  struct timeb Time_Struct;
  dummy=ftime(&Time_Struct);
  *UnixSysTime=Time_Struct.time;
}
```

Comment: `man ftime` ⇒ `SYNOPSIS: #include <sys/timeb.h>`. Also, `CONFORMING TO: ... This function is obsolete. Don't use it.`

Comment: @melpomene manpages ftw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
#include <sys/timeb.h>
```

after the other includes lines.

Then the compiler **WILL KNOW** his storage size

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the struct variable with the following:

```
  struct timeb Time_Struct;
```

The compiler is not aware of its definition. Hence, it can't allocate memory for it.
Include the header file where this struct is defined.

Answer (score -1):

In my system, ubunt 12.04 LTS, the location is /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys directory.

for 32bit machine its location is /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys.

Check timeb.h file for more details regarding struct timeb etc